# Generalize several text fields for selecting the entire text when focus is gained

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, focuslistener

I want each of several text fields in a panel to have center alignment and to have a focus listener that will select the entire field when focus is gained.

```
txtSelection = new JTextField("", 9);
txtInclusion = new JTextField("", 9);
txtExclusion = new JTextField("", 9);
...
```

I know how to do it one by one:

```
txtSelection.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

txtSelection.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {

  public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

    txtSelection.select(0, 9);
  }
});
```

But **I'd rather not repeat that structure** for all the text fields.

I tried this (and a couple of varieties) but the **code seems to do nothing**:

```
pnlConditions = new JPanel();
pnlConditions.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

for(final Component c : pnlConditions.getComponents())  // compiler insisted on 'final'
{
  ((JTextField)c).setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

  if(c instanceof JTextField)
  {
    c.addFocusListener
      (new FocusAdapter()
        {
          @Override public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) 
          {
            ((JTextField)c).select(0,9);   // compiler suggested cast to JTextComponent; no difference
          }
        }
      );
  }
}
```

**The entire field is not selected; alignment is left (the default).** I guess my first clues that it wouldn't work are the compiler's insisting that `c` must be `final` in the `for` and for suggesting that the cast should have been to `JTextComponent` in the statement with `select`; but it didn't make that suggestion on the statement with `setHorizontal...`.

I'm sure this can be done; but **how**?

---

Here's the entire method containing the snippets above:

```
  static void makePnlConditions(){
    JLabel lblSelections = new JLabel("Select ONLY combos with ALL of:");
    JLabel lblInclusions = new JLabel("DE-select combo NOT containing one or more of:");
    JLabel lblExclusions = new JLabel("DE-select combo containing ANY of:");

    txtSelection = new JTextField("", 9);
    txtInclusion = new JTextField("", 9);
    txtExclusion = new JTextField("", 9);

    pnlConditions = new JPanel();
    pnlConditions.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    for(final Component c : pnlConditions.getComponents())
    {
      ((JTextField)c).setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

      if(c instanceof JTextField)
      {
        c.addFocusListener
          (new FocusAdapter()
            {
              @Override public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) 
              {
                ((JTextField)c).select(0,9);
              }
            }
          );
      }
    }

    pnlConditions.add(lblSelections);
    pnlConditions.add(txtSelection);
    pnlConditions.add(lblInclusions);
    pnlConditions.add(txtInclusion);
    pnlConditions.add(lblExclusions);
    pnlConditions.add(txtExclusion);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add the components into `JPanel` otherwise `pnlConditions.getComponents()` will return an empty array and no listener will be added for `JTextField`.

If you want to select entire text then use [JTextComponent#selectAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#selectAll%28%29) method.

Sample code:

```
JPanel pnlConditions = new JPanel();
pnlConditions.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

pnlConditions.add(lblSelections);
pnlConditions.add(txtSelection);
pnlConditions.add(lblInclusions);
pnlConditions.add(txtInclusion);
pnlConditions.add(lblExclusions);
pnlConditions.add(txtExclusion);

for (final Component c : pnlConditions.getComponents()) {      
    if (c instanceof JTextField) {
        ((JTextField) c).setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        ...
    }
}
```

---

> I want each of several text fields in a panel to have center alignment and to have a focus listener that will select the entire field when focus is gained.

Create a custom class that extends `JTextField`, provide all default implementation and use it everywhere in your application to make it centralized.

Sample code:

```
class MyJTextField extends JTextField {

    // Initialization block that is called for all the constructors
    {
        this.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                selectAll();
            }
        });
        this.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    }

    public MyJTextField() {}
    public MyJTextField(String text) {super(text);}
    public MyJTextField(int columns) {super(columns);}
    public MyJTextField(String text, int columns) {super(text, columns);}
}
```

Comment: @Braj---thanks! My apparent misconception that the field has to be complete before adding to panel prevented me from doing what you made obvious: move the loop below all the adds. That's all it took. I also apprecieate you advising me about `selectAll`; I'd missed that, too, though `select(0,9)` does the job, though not efficiently.

Comment: @Braj--FYI--I made a method `centerAndSelect(JPanel p)` to do the tasks I asked about. I call it from two different places in this program and will use it (and probably extend it) a LOT from here on, I think! (I just realized there's a second part of your answer, about extending JTextField... gotta study that.)... (Just did! COOL!)

Comment: Yes there are lots of ways to generalize it. 1.) Create a separate method to move the common code 2.) Create custom class as suggested. Choose any one that is easier as per your current application design and coding.